# How can I find an agent that would help me get my foot into the door of a publisher?

Tags: publishing, business

I have submitted my game for review at couple of game publishers with zero response.

My game is very specific and unusual, so maybe I need to find very specific publisher, or maybe it hasn't been noticed in the sea of submissions, maybe the game is not worth publishing. In any case, I need to know for sure which reasons it is and I need to try all the options available before giving up.

Therefore I've been looking for a professional who knows how and where to try these options, but I'm at a loss on what would be the process to find such a person.

What would be the process to find such an agent?

Comment: Is your aim just to market your game? In this case there are countless websites and companies that if you pay them, they will advertise your game for you, have you searched that online? Last time I uploaded an app on android I got a lot of spam e-mail of people wanting to be paid to market my game, I'm pretty sure there's more than enough people that do that.

Comment: hi, Tom, my intention is a little different. I know there are tons of app marketing provides, however I'm looking for an agent, who could find me an app publisher - a company which is ready to market the app on their expense in return for shared profits. Do you have idea where are could find such agent?

Comment: Unless you've made big successes in the past, that makes people know you have potential for profit, I doubt anyone will invest their time to market a game for "shared profits".

Comment: Hello Huselius. Since asking for resources is considered off-topic here, I have reworded the question so that you could get help in finding out how you could find these resources.

Comment: Tom, Im not searching for development investor. The app is finished. All I need is exposure. Many publishers dont need to invest a dime, just market within their own apps, which have millions of downloads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, the options are somewhat limited. In a [2003 interview with Gamasutra](https://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131247/game_agents_show_me_the_money_.php?page=2), Mark Long states: "shopping for an agency is a pretty simple task right now, since only a handful exist".  Unlike other fields, game development is comparable new. Also, there's the theory offered in a [NY Time's piece on game agencies](https://www.nytimes.com/2010/03/27/technology/27agent.html) that "a deep cultural divide between the slick, Armani-suit-wearing agent crowd and rumpled computer-code-writing gamers has proven difficult to bridge." Both these pieces are a bit dated, but there doesn't seem to have been a huge amount of growth since then.

That being said, there are some agents & agencies out there. Starting with a web search for "game development agents" I was able to find one agency straight off. It turned up a couple of articles (such as those linked above) that in turn lead me to a few more.  In short, you're going to need to grind the web & do some professional networking to work up some leads.

That being said, I also want to address what seems to be a bit of a disconnect in the question comments. You state that you're not looking for any money or funding because your app is already finished. That may be true, but marketing your game to a publisher still represents an expense to *somebody*. Your "future profit sharing" proposition requires the agency to take a calculated risk their expenses for finding you a deal will be offset by future revenue. There's often a considerable financial gap between developing a game & its profitable release - even previously successful AAA studios struggle with this.

Comment: Pikalek, thank you for detailed response. Addressing your last point, I understand that in many cases promotion is more expensive than development, however my idea was to find some at least semi-decent game developer/publisher, who would wish to promote my app in their already established gaming network, e.g. within their existing games which have millions of downloads - these things basically don't cost them a thing, because their games are marketing platform which they already own. I don't understand why they wouldn't be open to take a share of the app by promoting it within their network